# Windows 10 does not let set screen brightness for in a power plan

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I've recently got a brand new laptop with Windows 10 Home edition installed. I haven't had any experience with the OS before, so i might be missing something. In Windows 7 I could manage the screen brightness for a laptop separately for different power options (e.g. 70% when the laptop works from battery and 100% when it works from ac power). However in Win 10 it doesn't seem to be an option anymore. First I couldn't find corresponding options under power plan settings window. I still can set this via `powercfg` command line tool though, but it gives somewhat unexpected behavior. It looks like system enforces battery/AC settings to match each other. For example if I set my power settings as follows:

```
> powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX {powerPlan_GUID} {screenGroup_GUID} {screenBrightness_GUID} 100
> powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX {powerPlan_GUID} {screenGroup_GUID} {screenBrightness_GUID} 70
```

It shows correct values under the settings request afterward:

```
> powercfg -q
...
GUID настройки питания: {screenBrightness_GUID}
    Минимальная возможная настройка: 0x00000000
    Максимальная возможная настройка: 0x00000064
    Инкремент возможных настроек: 0x00000001
    Единицы возможных настроек: %
Текущий индекс настройки питания от сети: 0x00000064
Текущий индекс настройки питания от батарей: 0x00000046
...
```

It even sets the brightness once (when i plug or unplug the power cable) but then it stops working and the same request returns equal values:

```
> powercfg -q
...
GUID настройки питания: {screenBrightness_GUID}
    Минимальная возможная настройка: 0x00000000
    Максимальная возможная настройка: 0x00000064
    Инкремент возможных настроек: 0x00000001
    Единицы возможных настроек: %
Текущий индекс настройки питания от сети: 0x00000046
Текущий индекс настройки питания от батарей: 0x00000046
...
```

Is that something Windows does not support anymore or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please provide an English translation to the outputs to those commands.  Questions are expected to be in English.

Comment: Check the Power Plan settings.  Depending on the laptop model, there may not be a setting for brightness when unplugged.  This idea has been replaced on some kinds of laptops with shorter display turn off intervals and battery saver implementation on low battery.